Form data not being recognized by nodejs
I have the following code in React frontend
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("file", values.file.file);
 formData.append("fileName", values.file.fileName);
 formData.append("image", values.image);
 formData.append("body", values.body);
 formData.append("bookId", values.bookId);

 axios.put("/api/admin/visuals/" + this.props.match.params.id, formData)
 .then((response) => {

In node js backend, I have the following code
router.put("/:id", checkAdminAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    let upload = null;
    let input = req.body;

    if (id > 0) {
        try {
            console.dir(req.body);

            if (req.body.file) {
                upload = await Common.uploadMedia(req, res);
                input.image = upload;
                console.dir("Uploaded new file");
            }

            await Visuals.update(input, id);

            return res.json({
                status: "ok",
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.dir(error);
            return res.json({
                status: "error",
            });
        }
    }
});

I have two issues

req.body is empty
req.body.file is empty

Does someone know why?

Have to tried setting the Content-Type to multipart/form-data?

@Ivar Yes that didn't work

Are you using a middleware that handles bodies of type multipart/form-data? Multer being one of them for example.

Does it work if you use POST instead of PUT?

@Barmar It works for POST not PUT

Sounds to me like the middleware doesn't support file uploads in PUT.

@Barmar how can I add middleware to support file uploads in PUT?

What makes you think you can or should? File uploads are normally supposed to be done with POST, not PUT.

see How can i use multer with react?
